# How to add new line in spring application context as map value

Tags: java, spring

in my application context in spring I have defined a map:

```
<util:map map-class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">                        
                        <entry key="test" value="here I need to add new line" />
                    </util:map>
```

in value I need to add new line:

I try:

```
 <entry key="test" value="s
s" />
```

or

```
 <entry key="test" value="s\ns" />
```

but with no success

please help me

Answer (score 2):

try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference

```
<util:map id="map" map-class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
    <entry key="test" value="s&#10;s" />
</util:map>
```